# Are postdocs students or staff when calculating staff/student ratios?

Tags: university, ranking

The ratio of staff/students is an important factor for university rankings. How are postdocs and non-faculty researchers considered in calculating this ratio?

I am referring to researchers who have an official contract with the university such as postdoc fellowships (which are competition based), higher level researchers like Senior Scientists (some universities give such titles) and even Research Professors?

To rephrase my question: **Are research staff considered part of "staff" in staff/student ratio?** They are not academic staff but they can do teaching jobs too!

Comment: This is a difficult question for a globally valid answer. For a start, I suspect even the concept of "academic staff" is not clearly enough defined world-wide to generally allow for the statement "[research staff/postdocs] are not academic staff". And of course, the same question can be asked about doctoral candidates, who are, depending on the place, officially registered only as students, officially registered only as employees, or sometimes even both at a time (with either one or both being obligatory).

Comment: Agree with @O.R.Mapper. Not every place uses staff/student ratio. Many locations use Faculty/Student  or Teachers/Students ratio..

Comment: @scaaahu: I think that points to a wider concern: While the meaning of "academic staff" may be clearly defined in some places, the "staff/student" ratio may well refer to [the word "staff" in its general sense](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/staff), as the entirety of people employed by the university, rather than the narrower definition of ["academic staff"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faculty_%28academic_staff%29); or possibly anything in between (e.g. anyone employed by the university who has any connection to teaching).

Comment: This factor is used for the university ranking! If it cannot be calculated with a normalized system, how comparing universities ?

Comment: @user40951: That is one of the reasons why such rankings should be taken with caution.

Comment: @user40951: As an afterthought, note that if you find a "normalized system", you should *still* take the resulting ratio with caution. Depending on the university system and culture, the way e.g. a Bachelor student is taught differs *extremely* from the way e.g. a doctoral candidate is "taught".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OK with caution! but how they are calculated? Based on each university system/claim? For example, they consider PhD students as staff in some countries? Or when somewhere staff/student ration is given, we never know who has been counted?

Comment: @user40951: there is really no general answer. In some countries, yes, PhD students are considered university employees, in others not. For example, in Italy where I live, PhD students and postdocs are not considered staff because these are not permanent positions. Permanent researchers are instead considered staff, and are considered in the student/staff ratio because researchers can (and somehow should) teach classes.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Then, you mean, Italian universities generally get worse ranking than similar universities in countries in which postdoc/PhD is counted as staff in ranking systems considering staff/student ratio?

Comment: @user40951: I really don't know, I never cared about rankings, so I never analysed which factors go into defining them.

Answer (score 17):

For the US, there is actually a fairly standardized answer, though it's complicated.  The short version appears to be:

> Postdocs who teach count as 1/3 of a staff member.  Postdocs who do not teach are not counted at all.

First, note that the number usually used in the US is **student-faculty ratio**. (Not "staff": in US academic parlance, "staff" typically refers to non-academic university employees: administrative assistants, accountants, gardeners, cooks, etc.)

We can pretty quickly eliminate the possibility of postdocs being counted as students - I've never heard of postdocs being considered students anywhere in US academia.  They don't enroll in classes nor work towards a degree.  (Even for PhD students working exclusively on research enroll in classes each term until they graduate, typically a 12-credit course called "Independent Research" or something similar.  Postdocs do not.)

So, are they counted as faculty?

There is an organization called the [Common Data Set Initiative](http://www.commondataset.org/) which sets forth standard definitions for university statistics like student-faculty ratio.  CDS doesn't actually gather data or publish survey instruments, but their [set of standards and definitions](http://www.commondataset.org/docs/2014-2015/CDS_2014-2015.htm) is written in questionnaire form.

Item I-2, "Student to Faculty Ratio", says:

> Report the Fall 2014 ratio of full-time equivalent students (full-time plus 1/3 part-time) to full-time equivalent instructional faculty (full-time plus 1/3 part-time). In the ratio calculations, exclude both faculty and students in stand-alone graduate or professional programs such as medicine, law, veterinary, dentistry, social work, business, or public health in which faculty teach virtually only graduate-level students. Do not count undergraduate or graduate student teaching assistants as faculty.

For the definition of "instructional faculty", we refer to Item I-1, which has a table explaining how various types of faculty members should be counted.  For

> instructional faculty in preclinical and clinical medicine, faculty who are not paid (e.g., those who donate their services or are in the military), or research-only faculty, post-doctoral fellows, or pre-doctoral fellows

it says they should *not* count as full-time instructional faculty, and should be counted as part-time instructional faculty "only if they teach one or more non-clinical credit courses".

So this is the answer.  A postdoc or other researcher who does not teach any non-clinical credit-bearing courses should not be counted in the student-faculty ratio.  A postdoc who does teach at least one such course should be counted a part-time instructional faculty member, and contribute 1/3 of a person to the denominator of the ratio.

Of course, it should be kept in mind that this data is provided voluntarily by each institution, and it is ultimately up to the institution to decide how they classify each of their employees.

With regard to rankings, the best-known rankings in the US are the [*US News & World Report* Best Colleges Rankings](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges).  They [explain](http://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/how-us-news-collects-rankings-data) that they generally follow the CDS definitions when collecting data from institutions.

Comment: And here I was thinking the three fifths compromise was a thing of the past... Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK post-doctoral researchers are staff, and their research is included in the REF (UK research rating table, which is bogus and biased due to oxbridge domination (separate issue)).

Technically if you are paying income tax then you are a member of staff not a student. Students get stipends or nothing.